# Can I modify input parameters using postsharp?

Tags: c#, postsharp

i want to create an attribute using postsharp that will HTMLIncode input parameters. Something like this:

```
public void Mymethod([HTMLEncode]string parm1,[HTMLEncode]string parm2){
    ....
}
```

I want to place it selectively on input parameters. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The method's input parameters can be modified using [MethodInterceptionAspect](https://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception). In your particular case you can implement an [IAspectProvider](https://doc.postsharp.net/iaspectprovider) in your `HTMLEncodeAttribute` class and provide the interception aspect on the corresponding declaring method. For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class HTMLEncodeAttribute : Attribute, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        ParameterInfo parameter = (ParameterInfo)targetElement;
        IAspectRepositoryService aspectRepositoryService = PostSharpEnvironment.CurrentProject.GetService<IAspectRepositoryService>();

        if (!aspectRepositoryService.HasAspect(parameter.Member, typeof(HTMLEncodeImplAspect)))
        {
            yield return new AspectInstance(parameter.Member, new HTMLEncodeImplAspect());
        }
    }
}

[PSerializable]
public class HTMLEncodeImplAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    private List<int> encodedParams;

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        this.encodedParams = new List<int>();
        ParameterInfo[] allParams = method.GetParameters();
        for (int i = 0; i < allParams.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allParams[i].GetCustomAttribute(typeof(HTMLEncodeAttribute)) != null)
            {
                this.encodedParams.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        foreach (int p in this.encodedParams)
        {
            args.Arguments.SetArgument(p, "encoded value");
        }
        args.Proceed();
    }
}
```